# Problems Appear in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I am a beginner at coding and currently in a python class at my university. I'm having some issues pop up in the "Problems" tab in Visual Studio Code. It wants me to put a self argument in my function inside a class, however when I call the class in my other file the code works it just displays problems. I tried putting self into the classes code and then everything stops working. The code was copied during the lecture and is the same code as my professor's using the same coding platform however his code doesn't show problems. I am attaching 2 screen shoots since the code is from 2 different files. I'm guessing something in my settings is causing this to happen. I have a similar thing happen when I do something like.`for i in something:` it will tell me i isn't defined yet the code will work.
[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VwM50.jpg)
[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCBiw.jpg)

Comment: If this is the same code as your professor he/she needs to follow a programming course in Python. What is the use of the class `Math_functions`? You are not programming Java or C#.

Answer (score 0):

Inside a class, that has non static methods, there must be a self variable.

```
class Math_Functions:
    def addition(self, x, y): # there must be a self
        return x + y

    #... so on
```

This seems to be a static method, but VC may require you to still provide a self reference. Because python (at this specific case) does not require the self reference by default, when imported your code works file, but standalone, VC may tell you that you need an extra self there. Also you have an extra comma in `addition` after your y parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Just simply pass in self into each of the methods (math functions), although it may work without it, it's good practice to do this if you want to continue learning OOP.

```
class mathFunctions:
    def add(self, x, y): #Avoids the problem in VS 
        return x + y
```

It is required to pass in self for it to work when creating an object using a class using **init**, for example:

```
class employee:
    def __init__(self, firstName, lastName, age):
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
        self.age = age
      
    def fullName(self):
        return self.firstName + ' ' + self.lastName
#creating an object within the class
John = employee('John', 'Smith', '26')
#Returns "John Smith"
print(John.fullName())
```

Hope this might help, good luck on your python class!

Answer (score 0):

This is a response to both replies. Putting self into the code creates a different problem and the code won't run because it tells me I am "missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'"[image: Screenshot 1][image: Screenshot 2]

Answer (score 0):

Three solutions:

First One:

In settings.json file add this configuration:

```
"python.linting.pylintArgs": [
    "--disable=all",
    "--enable=F,E,unreachable,duplicate-key,unnecessary-semicolon,global-variable-not-assigned,unused-variable,binary-op-exception,bad-format-string,anomalous-backslash-in-string,bad-open-mode",
    "--disable=no-self-argument"
  ],
```

The first and second settings are the default settings of pylint, the third one can suppress the warning.

Second One:

Change your code to these:

main:

```
from calc import Math_functions as mf

print("Welcom to Calculator!")

x = int(input('Number: '))
y = int(input('Number: '))
op = input('Operation: ')

f = mf(x, y)

if op == '+':
    print(f.addition())
elif op == '-':
    print(f.subtraction())
elif op == '*':
    print(f.multiplication())
elif op == '/':
    print(f.division())
```

calc:

```
class Math_functions:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def addition(self):
        return self.x+self.y

    def subtraction(self):
        return self.x-self.y

    def multiplication(self):
        return self.x*self.y

    def division(self):
        return self.x/self.y
```

Third One:

Change your code to these:

main:

```
import calc as mf

print("Welcom to Calculator!")

x = int(input('Number: '))
y = int(input('Number: '))
op = input('Operation: ')


if op == '+':
    print(mf.addition(x, y))
elif op == '-':
    print(mf.subtraction(x, y))
elif op == '*':
    print(mf.multiplication(x, y))
elif op == '/':
    print(mf.division(x, y))
```

calc:

```
def addition(x, y):
    return x+y


def subtraction(x, y):
    return x-y


def multiplication(x, y):
    return x*y


def division(x, y):
    return x/y
```

Comment: where do I enter the stuff in the settings.json file? I'm very new to programming and therefor don't know these things. I need step by step guidance. I have recently had a similar issue with code when I imported tkinter I got about 100 problems.

Comment: yes, the first solution is to make changes in settings.json. others are changing the code.